# How do I differentiate this quadratic function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^TQx-b^Tx$, where Q is a symmetric positive definite matrix. Apparently $\nabla f(x)=Qx-b$, I want to find $\nabla ^2f(x)$, does anyone have any idea how to do this?

http://www.bioinfo.org.cn/~wangchao/maa/Numerical_Optimization.pdf - page 47 for reference.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that we have here is yet another user who does not accept answers. You probably believe that we are some sort of slaves here, our only purpose in life being to help people like you for free. Your philosophy seems to be squeezing as much as you can from the others, without giving those suckers anything back. Not a respectable philosphy of life, if you ask me. With time, people will begin avoiding your questions and you won't get answers anymore. Nobody expects you to accept answers to all the questions, but there are some very good ones among those that you have received so far.

Comment: How have I not accepted answers? I have made no comment on the answers given. Both of the answers below are very helpful, exactly what I was looking for and I accept them. I did not ask just for an answer, I asked how to do the problem. I am not coercing anyone into answering this question, they have the freedom of choice. I am grateful for all answers offered and understand the significant time and effort put into them.

Comment: I do not know whether you are aware of how asking and answering questions work here, so I suggest that you read about [accepting answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and also follow the links therein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be convenient to work in coordinates. If $x = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix}$, $Q = (q_{ij})_{1 \le i,j \le n}$ and $b = \begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ \vdots \\ b_n \end{pmatrix}$, then $f(x) = \frac 1 2 \sum _{i,j} q_{ij} x_i x_j + \sum _i b_i x_j$.

When you compute any 2nd order partial derivative of $f$, the term $b^T x$ vanishes because it contains the variables $x_i$ only at the power $1$.

When you compute $\frac {\partial^2 f} {\partial x_i^2}$ you essentially derive $\frac 1 2 q_{ii} x_i ^2$ twice, and get $q_{ii}$, because all the other terms contain the variable $x_i$ only at the power $1$, so they vanish.

When you compute $\frac {\partial^2 f} {\partial x_i \partial x_j}$ you essentially derive $\frac 1 2 q_{ij} x_i x_j + \frac 1 2 q_{ji} x_j x_i$ so you get $\frac 1 2 (q_{ij} + q_{ji})$. Since $Q$ is assumed symmetric, this is in fact $q_{ij}$.

Putting everything together, you get that $\Bbb d^2 f = \sum _{ij} q_{ij} \Bbb d x_i \Bbb d x_j$.

Answer (score 0):

It is just $Q$. I would suggest you to take a look at Multivariate calculus before trying to learn Optimization. In your question, it is easy to see that for $n$-dimensional problem we have $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}q_{ij}x_ix_j - \sum_{i=1}^n b_ix_i$. Now define $\nabla^2 f(x) = H$ and using $H_{ij} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}$ try to calculate the matrix $H$ as an exercise. Finally you obtain each entry of $H$ to be coinciding with $Q$.